# Implementation of function "member" using "foldr" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, member, fold

I tried like that:

```
member e [] = False
member e xs = foldr (==) e xs
```

and then:

```
member 3 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I get this error message:

```
No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `3'
In the first argument of `memb', namely `3'
```

I don't know what it means... can someone help me?

PS: member is a function that, given a element and a list of elements, returns whether the element belongs to that list or not. The usual implementation is:

```
member a [] = False
member a (x:xs) | (a == x)  = True
                | otherwise = member a xs
```

PS2: full code

```
-- member:: Int -> [Int] -> Bool (Not necessary)
member e [] = False
member e xs = foldr (==) e xs

main = do
    putStrLn (show( member 3 [1,2,3] ) )
```

Comment: Try giving `member` the type signature you think it should have and see what the compiler tells you.

Comment: The last version is close to `foldr`: try using `if..then..else` instead of guards as an intermediate step. Use lambdas accordingly.

Comment: the mission is to make "member" using "foldr", I don't think its necessary to use "if...else...then".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there, but as you can see your types don't line up.  It would have been better if you had given `member` an explicit type signature, I'm guessing that you want something like

```
member :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

This would have made the compiler complain that this doesn't type check instead of failing when you tried to use it.  The problem is that `foldr (==)` has the type `Bool -> [Bool] -> Bool`, not quite what you were expecting.

Instead, what you want is something more like

```
member e xs
    = foldr (||)
            False
            (map (e ==) xs)
```

I've split up the arguments onto separate lines here so that it's easier to see what the arguments to `foldr` actually are.  The big idea here is to convert the list of values into a list of `Bool`s, then use the or operator (`||`) to reduce the list into a single `Bool`.  Since Haskell is lazy by default, `map (e ==) xs` won't actually compute anything until elements are needed by `foldr`, so you won't necessarily compare every element in the list to `e`.

You could implement this directly with only `foldr` with a more complicated accumulator (the first argument to `foldr`):

```
member e xs = foldr (\x acc -> if acc then x else e == x) False xs
```

Which can equivalently be written as

```
member e xs = foldr (\x acc -> acc || e == x) False xs
```

Notice how in this case we have to perform `e == x` for every `x` in `xs` until we find a case where `acc` is `True`.  This is why I chose `map (e ==)` earlier, I just separated the step of performing the comparison from the step of accumulating the values.

One thing to keep in mind with `foldr` (and most other folds) is that the second argument, also called the initial value, has to have the same type as final result of `foldr`.  In this case you're wanting `foldr` to return a `Bool`, so the second argument must be a `Bool` as well.

A trick for working through these problems, provided you have a new enough version of GHC, is typed holes.  These allow you to put in "holes" in an expression and the compiler will tell you what type that hole should be, so if you do

```
member :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
member e xs = foldr _1 _2 xs
```

GHC will print out

```
Found hole `_1` with type: a -> Bool -> Bool
...
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a]
  e :: a

Found hole `_2` with type: Bool
...
Relevant bindings include
  xs :: [a]
  e :: a
```

This tells you that the function given to `foldr` must have the type `a -> Bool -> Bool` and the initial value must have type `Bool`.  Since `e` has type `a` you can't put it as is in that hole.  This technique can help guide you through defining your functions, particularly when you aren't sure of all the types, with the compiler telling you what to use for each argument.

Comment: Isn't it much better to flip the arguments to `||` in `foldr (\x acc -> acc || e == x) False`, to avoid searching past the first match? Or, using the equivalent section, `foldr (\x -> (x == e ||) False`? I think that must be what you intended, since you mention in your answer that it is lazy, which it's actually not.

Comment: Did you mean `member e xs = foldr (\x acc -> if x == e then True else acc) False xs` ? @bheklilr

Answer (score 0):

We know that, with a pseudocode syntax,

```
foldr g z []            = z
foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] = g a (foldr g z [b,c,...,n])
```

and we know that we want it to be

```
member x []            = False
member x [a,b,c,...,n] = (x==a) || member x   [b,c,...,n]
                       = foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] 
                       = g   a     (foldr g z [b,c,...,n])
                                   ------------------------ r
                       = (x==a) || (foldr g z [b,c,...,n])
                       = foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] 
                           where 
                               { z     = False ; 
                                 g a r = (x==a) || r }  --- r
```

and so with the regular Haskell syntax we define

```
member x  =  foldr g False  where  { g a r = (x==a) || r }
```